# Object structure changed internally

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to populate Highcharts from an object. The chart loaded fine initially, but then the source object gets changed. It's a little tough to tell, if you would kindly check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdfahim/k9s5L3na/3/) code and do following:

Click Button1 => chart loads with data `[687, 687]` as expected.

Click Button2 => chart loads with data `[546, 546]` as expected.

Again, click Button1 => Nothing happens because `getAllData.T1.C1.M1` is now changed from `[687, 687]` to `[Object, Object]`.

Again, click Button2 => chart loads with data `[546, 546]` as expected (please see `console.log` output below).

Can anybody please explain?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdfahim/k9s5L3na/3/)

Below is the `console.log` I get in my Chrome for each button click.

```
[687, 687]
[546, 546]
[Object, Object]
  0: Object
    y: 687
    __proto__: Object
  1: Object
    y: 687
    __proto__: Object
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array[0]
[546, 546]
```

Comment: You need to set the 4th arg of [`Series.setData`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) (*updatePoints*) to `false`.

Comment: wow .. can you please elaborate what is that? I read Highcharts documentation, but didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you need to set the *updatePoints* argument of [`Series.setData`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) to `false` to prevent Highcharts from simply updating the existing data points (it does this due to your data sets being the same length).

Something like this should suffice and preserve animations.

```
chart.series[0].setData(data[0], false, false, false);
chart.redraw();
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9s5L3na/4/)</kbd>

Comment: ya, it definitely works .. so "updating the existing data points" means it just change the source (asking for my learning purpose)?

Comment: also, shouldn't 3rd param should be true to preserve animation?

Comment: @AbdFahim when using the default *updatePoints*, Highcharts modifies the passed in data array directly. Because these are passed by reference in JavaScript, it means the original array is modified.

Comment: @AbdFahim it doesn't actually matter what you pass in for *animation* as it is set to `false` internally when *updatePoints* is `false`. That's why I set *redraw* to `false` and call `chart.redraw()` instead.

Comment: @Phil .. thanks for explanation. But unfortunately, like you said, I loose nice animation. Btw, just thinking why updatePoints = true causes a nested array? E.g. original array was [], when it updates array, it becomes [[],[]] ! Also, why other series does not have this problem? As a matter of fact, if you have, let say, 4 arrays, only first array (which ever clicked first) gets affected. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abdfahim/k9s5L3na/5/

Comment: @AbdFahim my answer should still have animations (it does for me in the JSFiddle). I'm not sure what it does to the data internally, I didn't look that deeply into the source. Feel free to dig around ~ https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/v4.1.6/js/highcharts.src.js#L13300

Answer (score 0):

There must be a bug in the updatePoint method.
Try this: `chart.series[0].setData(data[0], true, false, false);` (data, redraw, animation, updatePoints)

Comment: It's definitely not a bug. This answer works but you lose animations

Comment: That's why I've listed the arguments in my answer, so anyone reading it can pick their preferences without looking up what those false/true mean. Might not be a bug, but poor coding then.